# Question on limit of power of rational functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $k$ be a fixed number and suppose that $q_k$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients. In other words $$q_k(y) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}b_i y^i$$ where $b_i, \quad 0 \le i \le k$ are rationals.

Here is my question: I need want to show that either $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle \frac{2^n}{\displaystyle e^{q_k(n)}} = 0$$ or $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle e^{q_k(n)}}{2^n} = 0.$$

I know that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 0$$ so the first thing that comes to my mind is that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle e^{q_k(n)}}{2^n}$$  has to be zero if the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle e^{q_k(n)}$ is finite which I think is infinty. How can I approach this question? Any help on this will be great.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $n \to \infty$?  The limits as $n \to 0$ are not $0$.

Comment: Yes it is infinity. @RobertIsrael Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The case for $k =0$ is clear to me. I am still thinking about the other two cases.

Comment: Look at $\lim_{n \to \infty} q(n)- n \log 2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} q(n)( 1- \frac{n \log 2}{b_k n^k})=\pm \infty$. Thus your limit is $e^{\pm \infty} $

Comment: @reuns I am sorry I really cant see how that helps me get the limit to be zero. Can you please elaborate? 

I could easily see that the limit is zero when k= 0 as advised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is simple and its sketch is already provided in [Robert Israel’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2438228/71850).

Decreasing $k$ if necessarily, without loss of generality we may assume $b_k\ne 0$. Put $x_n=\frac{2^n}{\displaystyle e^{q_k(n)}}=e^{n\ln 2-q_k(n)}$ and $y_n=n\ln 2-q_k(n)$.

So if $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=-\infty$ then  $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{y_n}=0$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=+\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-y_n}=0$. Thus it suffices to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=-\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=+\infty$. This clearly holds if $k>1$. If $k=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=+\infty$, so  $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-y_n}=0$.

It remains to consider case $k=1$. Then $y_n=n(\ln 2-b_1)-b_0$. To show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=+\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=-\infty$ it suffices to remark that $\ln 2=\log_e 2$ is irrational, so $\ln 2-b_1\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases to consider, depending on whether the degree $k$ is $0$, $1$ or greater than $1$.  The only one that's not really obvious is $k=1$.  For this, 
 the important fact is that $\ln(2)$ is irrational.  This follows from the 
fact that $e$ is transcendental.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $e \approx 2.7 > 2.5= \dfrac {5}{2}$.

You say that case $k=0$ is clear to you.

Let´s go on $k \geq 1$ then.

Suppose that $b_k>0$. Then for large enough $n$ we will have $q_k(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}b_i n^i>n$. For large enough $n$ we will also have $e^{q_k(n)}> \left (\dfrac {5}{2} \right)^{q_k(n)}=\dfrac {5^{q_k(n)}}{2^{q_k(n)}}$.

So we have $0<\dfrac {1}{e^{q_k(n)}}<\dfrac {2^{q_k(n)}}{5^{q_k(n)}}$.

So we have $0<\dfrac {{2^{q_k(n)}}}{e^{q_k(n)}}<\dfrac {2^{q_k(n)}\cdot2^{q_k(n)}}{5^{q_k(n)}}=\dfrac {4^{q_k(n)}}{5^{q_k(n)}}=\left (\dfrac {4}{5} \right)^{q_k(n)}$.

Now take a break and eat your favourite [sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and take the limit.

Can you now handle the case when $b_k<0$?